# Join on second table if value not found in first table

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to join on a second table only if the results of the first join are blank. Below is a subsection of Table A data:

```
ID  Metro   Submarket 
1   NYC     Manhattan
2   NYC     Brooklyn
3   NYC     Queens
4   NYC     Bronx
5   NYC     Newark
```

The tables I'm using for the joins are:

```
Table B                                         Table C         
Metro   Submarket   A.Price B.Price C.Price     Metro   A.Price B.Price C.Price
NYC     Manhattan   54      32      48          NYC     50      49      69
NYC     Queens      35      39      59          Philly  49      48      37
NYC     Brooklyn    20      49      58          Chicago 20      48      36
NYC     Bronx       49      30      20                  
NYC     Newark      49      50      -
```

I'm adding the Price columns from Table B to Table A based on a Metro and Submarket match. However, Table B doesn't have all the prices. If I can't find a match in Table B then I want to look into Table C for a match only on Metro.

For ID 5, we can find the A and B prices in Table B. However, the C price is blank. In that case, I want it to retrieve the C price from Table C (69 is what it would choose).

I'm using SAS 9.4. SQL, macros, or anything else SAS can handle is welcome!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can left join both tables to the main table and simply use `COALESCE()`. This will give you the value if present in `Table B`, otherwise it will give you the value in `Table C`:

```
PROC SQL;

CREATE TABLE Output AS

SELECT
    ta.ID,
    ta.Metro,
    ta.Submarket,
    COALESCE(tb.A_Price,tc.A_Price) AS A_Price,
    COALESCE(tb.B_Price,tc.B_Price) AS B_Price,
    COALESCE(tb.C_Price,tc.C_Price) AS C_Price
FROM
    tablea ta
LEFT JOIN
    tableb tb
    ON  (tb.Metro = ta.Metro)
    AND (tb.Submarket = ta.Submarket)
LEFT JOIN
    tablec tc
    ON  (tc.Metro = ta.Metro);

QUIT;
```